# How to replace a specific character in MIPS?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

So, as the question asks, I am wondering how can i replace a specific character in MIPS?

I store the character I want to replace in $s0, using

```
addi $s0, $v0, 0
```

I store character I want to replace it with in $s1, using

```
addi $s1, $v0, 0
```

Now, my loop so far loops like this:

```
 la $t0, userInput

 replaceLoop:
 lbu $t2, 0($t0)    #load our input's first char is at
 addi $t0, $t0, 1   #increment address of our string.
 beq $t2, $s0, replace #check if char in input, matches
 beq $t2, $0, end      #char we want to replace.
```

So what it is supposed to do is first ask "Is the character i am currently pointing at in the userInput matching the character I want to replace?" If so, go to replace command. Question is, how would I write the replace? I am just beginning to learn MIPS, so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Figured out the issue; redacted for now until turned in.

Comment: `sb $s1, -1($t0); b replaceLoop;`

Comment: Could you explain what it does and how it does it?

Comment: `sb` is **s**tore **b**yte, from the source (in this case `$s1`) to the address given. The address is one less than `$t0`, since you already incremented the address before the conditional branch. Afterwards, jump back to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: I see, now how would i then go about printing the final string? Would it be something like li $v0, 4
  la $a0, final
  syscall
  
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, ($t0)
  #li $a1, 600
  syscall

Comment: Also, when i have it print userInput instead of t0, it seems to make the whole string be composed of the letter i wanted it to be replaced with.

Comment: You have not posted enough of your program to answer these additional questions. Also, I'm not personally familiar with MARS, so I'll leave this to someone else to answer (or you to look up some documentation).

Comment: Edited it to include the full code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108452/discussion-between-eof-and-somestudent).

Comment: @SomeStudent You must know that editing a question does not "redact" it. If you weren't supposed to post it here it's too late

Comment: No real restriction really. More of a people just skip over if they don't find an answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The hint as the answer lies within the replaceLoop, and has to do with a missing bne that jumps back to our loop.